# On separability of $L^2$ and others.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, weak-topology

I have two related questions:

Is $L^2(X,\mu)$ separable if $\mu$ is a probability measure that is Lebesgue except it may have finitely many atoms?

If I want to prove that a function is continuous in the weak topology of $L^2$ is it enough to show that it is sequentially continuous?

If the answer to the first question is yes, the second one would follow because then the $L^2$ space would be metrizable.

Thanks!

Comment: For the first question [see this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42310/when-is-l2x-separable)

Comment: If $\mu$ is purely atomic with finite number of atoms then  $L^{2}$ is just an Euclidean space and so it is separable. If you are just saying that $\mu$ has at most finite number of atoms then $L^{2}$ need not be separable.

Comment: Thanks. I meant a Lebesgue measure with some finite Dirac measures. Do you know if sequential continuity is enough for continuity? It may be related to the Eberlein-Smulian theorem.